nested ifs with string functions
I know I'm doing this wrong, I just can't wrap my head around how to do this the right way.
The data looks like this:



Contact_Name




4.029398448E9


+15711751271


405184723


+621738939183


+641751751



  IF
  (
      Contact_Name like '%E%',cast(Contact_Name AS NUMERIC),
      (
          IF
              (
                  Contact_Name like '+1%',LTRIM(Contact_Name,'+1'),
                  (
                      IF
                          (
                              Contact_Name like '+%',LTRIM(Contact_Name,'+'),Contact_Name
                          )
                  )
              )
      )
  ) as CN

I'm looking for the result to look like this:



CN




4029398448


5711751271


405184723


621738939183


641751751




Can't you just do a couple of string replaces? '+1' to ''; '.' to ''; and 'E9' to '' What's the range of exponent values you're seeing?

Ok, it looks like you want to replace '+1' before getting rid of the rest of the '+' characters (as you also did in the pseudo-code.) Other than that it shouldn't matter which order you do them. Are you sure that's the only dialing prefix?

Do note that a simple replace won't be sufficient if you see something like 4.02939844E9 because you would then need to account for the trailing zero digit that got dropped.

try below
select 
  Contact_Name, 
  regexp_replace(Contact_Name, r'\+1|\+|\.|\D\d*', '') as CN
from your_table    

with output

